# MSSQL Server - Finding Duplicates on more than one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find duplicate parties where the gtid is unique but there is duplicate records where the first, last name and DOB are duplicated. So for example there can be multiple records for the following :

gtid : 105 but there should not be more than 1 record for the following example:

```
gtid : 105, first name : john, last name : smith , dob: 12/05/1992
gtid : 105, first name : john, last name : smith, dob: 12/05/1992
```

Acceptable :

```
gtid : 105, first name : john, last name : smith , dob: 12/05/1992
gtid : 106, first name : john, last name : smith, dob: 12/05/1992
```

I have the following but it doesn't work :

```
SELECT DISTINCT GtId, CrmPartyId, LegalName, BusinessClass, RmFullName, PbeFullName, OverallClientStatus, OverallRpStatus,
```

FirstName + ' ' + LastName FullName, Dob
FROM Core.WeccoParty

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `gtid` in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE,
       MIN(gtid), MAX(gdid), COUNT(*)
FROM Staging.WECCO_Party_In
GROUP BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I don't want the gtid to appear more than once - only the name + dob can have duplicates though

Answer (score 0):

FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME should be in group by:

```
 SELECT 
        FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME  AS NAME, BIRTH_DATE
    FROM
        Staging.WECCO_Party_In
    GROUP BY
    FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE
    HAVING COUNT(FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME+' '+BIRTH_DATE) > 1
```

Comment: up to date sql -I need no count - but only every record returned where there is duplicate full name + DOB. GTID must be unique:                                        SELECT DISTINCT GtId, CrmPartyId, LegalName, BusinessClass, RmFullName, PbeFullName, OverallClientStatus, OverallRpStatus, 
FirstName + ' ' + LastName FullName, Dob
FROM Core.WeccoParty

Comment: modified the query, you can check now

Comment: the datatypes Nvarchar and date are incompatible in the add operator. I am getting this

Answer (score 0):

To `COUNT` `gdid` remove it from `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME Name, BIRTH_DATE, COUNT(*) TotalGdids
FROM Staging.WECCO_Party_In
GROUP BY FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use same clause in group by from distinct clause, try following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT gtid,
    FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME  AS NAME, BIRTH_DATE, COUNT(*)
FROM
    Staging.WECCO_Party_In
GROUP BY
gtid,FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```